# Django cache not working on apache server

Tags: django, apache, caching

I'm using Django 4.2 In my development env the cache is working fine(file-based cache) but when I deployed on Apache (windows), the cache stopped working. Some research mentioned something to do with middleware but I don't have any cache meddleware in development. I'm using view-based cache.